# Chai check Existence of Something

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, koa

I'm trying to verify that the route I added is there but I get an undefined is not a function error here: `routerUtil.setRoutes();`

I also observed that I get a syntax error in my routerUtil.js on line koaRouter.get as it doesn't recognize get.

[image]

**routerUtil.js**

```
'use strict';

var koaRouter = require('koa-router')();

var router = module.exports = {
    router: koaRouter,
    setRoutes: setRoutes()
};

function setRoutes()
{
    koaRouter.get('default', '/', function *(next){

    });
}
```

**myBddTest.js**

```
var routerUtil = require('../../../routes/routerUtil');
var should = require('chai').should();
var koa = require('koa')();

describe('Feature: GET SomeResource REST Endpoint', function () {

    context('Scenario: No Results Exist - SomeResource', function () {

        var uri = '/SomeResource';

        describe('Given: There is a REST endpoint for this SomeResource', function () {

            // PASSES
            it('should have a router available', function(done){
                routerUtil.router.should.be.a('object');
                done();
            });

            // FAILS
            it('should have a default endpoint', function(){
                routerUtil.setRoutes();
                routerUtil.router.routes.name('default').should.exist;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should export the function `setRoutes` not the result of the function call:

```
var router = module.exports = {
   router: koaRouter,
   setRoutes: setRoutes // note the missing brackets
};
```